# Colores incorrectos al guardar un JPG con JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, bufferedimage

Poseo un error al guardar el contenido que el usuario dibuje en el Canvas en un formato JPG, pues a pesar de que la imagen se guarda en la ruta indicada, los colores no corresponden al visualizado en la interfaz gráfica.

```
private void guardarCanva(ActionEvent event){

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File archivoAGuardar = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    
    if(archivoAGuardar != null){
        try {
        
            WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int)lienzo.getWidth(),(int)lienzo.getHeight());
            lienzo.snapshot(null, writableImage);
            RenderedImage imagenRenderizada = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
            ImageIO.write(imagenRenderizada, "jpg", archivoAGuardar);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al guardar la imagen");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("No se seleccionó archivo");
    }
}
```

La primera imagen corresponde a la interfaz gráfica mientras que la segunda es la imagen que guarda al ejecutar la línea de código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer es un bug [imagen guardada en tono rosa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548363/image-saved-in-javafx-as-jpg-is-pink-toned) . dice que se puede deber a que jpg no tiene canal alpha . Hice una aplicación javafx en una sola clase que puede testear . la salida es en "png" porque png es rgba , sí tiene canal alpha . De todas maneras la calidad de imagen puede ser mejor en png y no generar artefactos que en  la compresión de jpeg .  [jpeg vs png](https://es.digitaltrends.com/computadoras/formatos-jpeg-vs-png/)

javafx :

```
    public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(800, 600);
       

        GraphicsContext graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        draw(graphicsContext);

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane(canvas);
        
        File file = new File("output.png");
       
        
        WritableImage snapshot = canvas.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), new WritableImage(800, 600));
        RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null);
        
        try {
            ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png",file );
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public static void draw(GraphicsContext gc) {
          gc.setFill(Color.PINK);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
      
        gc.setFont(Font.font(STYLESHEET_MODENA, 80.0));
        gc.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        gc.fillText("texto dibujado", 80, 80);

        gc.stroke();
        gc.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        gc.setLineWidth(7.0);
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.appendSVGPath("M 226 279 L 196 388 L 82 386 L 177 449 L 139 557 L 229 486 L 320 555 L 280 448 L 373 383 L 259 388 L 226 279 z");
        gc.closePath();
        gc.stroke();

    }
}
```

el programa :
[image: snapshot javafx]

la salida (output.png):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]